# Why do my interface objects respond out of order?

Tags: objective-c

I have an IBAction for when a button is clicked:

```
- (IBAction)importButtonClicked:(id)sender
```

And I want a series of events to take place like:

```
[_progressLabel becomeFirstResponder]; // I tried this but to no effect
_progressLabel.stringValue = BEGIN_IMPORT_STRING;
[_importButton setEnabled:FALSE];
_fileField.stringValue = @"";
[_progressIndicator startAnimation:nil];
```

But what ends up happening is the _progressIndicator animation takes place before the _progressLabel text appears.  And often times the text won't appear untili the _progressIndicator animation has stopped.  How do I fix that?

Comment: Does it help if you put the code between `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]`? Assuming you're on a Core animation OS version that is.

Comment: CATransaction is not recognized, but I think you are on to something.  The issue isn't with this code block, it's that the next code block is taking up all the resources and this one is not getting completed before it is done.  But I am just using Appkit in a xib file.

Comment: Are you performing the 'heavy' work on the same thread synchronously? In that case it will block the UI and you might not get the behavior you want.

Comment: I am... just doing some reading on threads now.  I've never used them before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the work you're doing which takes time (I assume that's what the progress indicator is for) on a separate thread. You don't have to do this manually in Cocoa, but instead, use Grand Central Dispatch (GCD), NSOperationQueue or such a construct available. You'll find lots of resources on GCD.